# How to make decimal to integer manually

Tags: python

I want make decimal number to integer number manually. I have data as below:

```
A = np.array([
    [1.7, 3.8, 21.7, 19.7,3.6000001,81.5],
    [2.8, 8.0, 78.3, 82.3, 36.5, 11.1]
])
```

how to make condition for A if the number behind the comma is .1 + 9, .2 + 8, .3 + 7, .4 + 6, .5 + 5, .6 + 4, .7 + 3, .8 + 2, .9 + 1 ,.0 + 0

```
expected A is array([
    [2.0, 4.0, 22.0, 19.0, 4.0, 82.0]
    [3.0, 8.0, 79.0, 83.0, 37.0, 12.0]
])
```

After we successfully convert to decimal, I want to return the data to its original form. is it possible?

Note : I dont want use np.round(), because if I use np.round I can't restored back data to original form.

Comment: So basically you want to round up? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around

Comment: yeah, but If I used np.round I can't restored back the data to original form

Comment: because I need restored back data to original form

Comment: use a different object to store data ?

Comment: You should describe what you are trying to accomplish.  It seems you are confusing "Storage" and "Presentation".  If you need rounded values in some places, that is a "presentation" of the data that is not lossless (i.e. not reversible).

Answer (score 0):

The closest option is to round the nearest integer.

**In the case of `.5` or exactly halfway between rounded decimal values,, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value.**

**Example: Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.**.

That's the code for it

[numpy round numbers](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy-around)

```
import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([2.33, 4.7, 5.1, 6.2356, 7.88, 8.5, 6.6])
>>> np.rint(arr).astype(int)
array([2, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 7])
```

Comment: then can we restored arr to original form?

Comment: this is not expected output

Comment: To get the exact output, you have to write the custom function.